# iOS : Side scrolling Menu at the top of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to find the iOS UI name for the menu that allows you to select tabs. but rather than being at the bottom of the screen, it sits at the top.

Here is an example of it being used.

[image: ios top menu side scrolling]

Can anybody identify as I'd like to learn about implementing something like this?

All the best,
-C

EDIT:

Yes the menu is scrollable contains more than the 3 items shown above.

Comment: If you are looking for third party solution , this might be helpful , https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit .

Comment: Yes the menu is scrollable contains more than the 3 items shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is three different `UIButton` or some kind of view with `tapgesturerecognizer`. Because there is no native control available in iOS which works like it. You have to design it manually.

You can use scrollview also for horizontal scrolling effect!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can identify that.  It is called a `UIScrollView` with horizontal scrolling enabled.  It uses paging for scrolling between each section.  From the looks of it you are wanting a `UITableView` underneath the `UIScrollView` to show the details of the section you select.  You will just need to reload the tableview data when you select a new section.

Here is a quick link for how to accomplish that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18069281/3543861

Also, Ketan is absolutely wrong.  This is a classic use case for a horizontal `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Common names are Paged Menu, Segmented Menu or Horizontal Menu.

An example implementation can be found here: https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu but really there's a lot of them on GitHub that you can use as inspiration.